# C++ don't free data when overriding new and delete operators

Tags: c++, malloc, overriding, operator-keyword, free

I replaced new and delete operators globally for debugging and I'm getting strange behavior, it looks like C++ don't free the data when I call delete.

Minimal Code with Error:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

// Classes
class A
{
    int i;
public:
    A() { printf("Created A\n"); }
    virtual ~A() { printf("Destroyed A\n"); }
};
class B : public A
{
    int j;
public:
    B() { printf("Created B\n"); }
    ~B() { printf("Destroyed B\n"); }
};

unsigned int num_allocs = 0;
// Custom new/delete
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    void* p = malloc(size);
    printf("[+] %p (%u)\n", p, size);
    num_allocs += 1;
    return p;
}
void operator delete(void* p)
{
    printf("[-] %p\n", p);
    num_allocs -= 1;
    free(p);
}

struct Z
{
    int k;
};

int main()
{
    printf("Started\n");
    A* a = (B*)(new B);
    Z* z = new Z;
    printf("Will delete\n");
    delete a;
    delete z;
    printf("Finished\n");
    printf("Allocs: %u\n", num_allocs);
    return 0;
}
```

> Output (Compiling with MSYS2 + MinGW32 on Windows):

Started

[+] 003e1a50 (12)

Created A

Created B

[+] 003e8630 (4)

Will delete

Destroyed B

Destroyed A

Finished

Allocs: 2

> 2 allocations remaining! WHY???

Edit1: When I use -std=c++98 or -std=c++11 flag, the error disappears, the flags -std=c++14 and -std=c++1z reproduce the error.

Comment: It looks like your `operator delete` isn't being called.

Comment: I cant reproduce it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69ceb5d26a07b48f

Comment: `A* a = (B*)(new B);` why do you cast here?

Comment: to test virtual deletion

Comment: Looks good?
http://cpp.sh/5uavy

Comment: I think it is a MinGW bug

Comment: try stepping through the program in a debugger to see if the delete is being called.  I think rmalizia44 maybe right and this is MinGW bug with those two flags.  I was unable to google any such bug, so if you find that it is a MinGW bug I would file it with them.

Comment: I tested your code in CodeBlocks which uses the MinGW compiler and the delete is not being called.  It appears that the code is still using the original delete and not the overridden one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is calling a different `delete` function.  You should provide a definition for

```
void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size);
```

When using C++17, both `delete` function should also be `noexcept`.

Comment: It worked, should I define new[] and delete[] too? It's only on debug build

Comment: @rmalizia44 You should define those if you're using them.  Otherwise they'll use the global ones included in your library.